# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/drools/event/KnowledgeRuntimeEventManager

Tags: apache-axis, wso2

I created an axis2 project in WSO2 Carbon studio. This application basically

running a CEP application.I added drools 5.5.0 in the  build path. In the eclipse

console the program is running. But when I deploy this to into WSO2 AS it shows an error

while deploying Can any one help how to solve this problem.

```
INFO {org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer} -  The CEPEventHandler-1.0.0.aar service, which is not valid, caused java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/drools/event/KnowledgeRuntimeEventManager

at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.DefaultSchemaGenerator.<init>(DefaultSchemaGenerator.java:140)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.Utils.fillAxisService(Utils.java:453)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:389)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.buildServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:101)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.processServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:143)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:82)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:813)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:371)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:365)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:73)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:94)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.Scheduler$SchedulerTimerTask.run(Scheduler.java:93)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class Not found : org.drools.event.KnowledgeRuntimeEventManager
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentClassLoader.findClass(DeploymentClassLoader.java:92)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentClassLoader.loadClass(DeploymentClassLoader.java:273)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 19 more

[2013-03-08 14:44:39,106]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine} -  org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/drools/event/KnowledgeRuntimeEventManager
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that WSO2 AS can't find drools.
It might be in your eclipse, but it's not shipped to the server.

Try one of these options:

- Right click on Your eclipse project -> deployment Assembly -> add -> add Drools
- Added drools to your project lib
- Add drools to your application server lib folder

Answer (score 0):

If there are any 3rd party jars. Drop them into AS_HOME/repository/components/lib and restart the server.

Comment: I tried to drop the jar file and start running. Again showing the same error. I also modify the Axis2 service project Pom.xml and added dependencies of drools. No improvement.Kindly give me a suggestion why I cannot run this application from the server and still running inside eclipse IDE.